# Connect mariadb using python on a remote machine

Tags: python, shell, mariadb

My mariadb process is running as below on a **Remote** machine. Both my local & remote are linux servers

```
/azperm/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/azperm/var/mysql/etc/my.cnf --ssl-ca=/azperm/var/pki/ca.pem --ssl-key=/azperm/var/pki/key.pem --ssl-cert=/azperm/var/pki/cert.pem
```

How do I connect to it using python script. Then run few queries & validate the results?

I thought of trying this but I cant mention password in script directly.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host.name",
    port=3306,
    user="user",
    passwd="secret_password",
    db="database",
    ssl={'ssl':
            {'ca': '/path/to/ca/ca',
             'key': '/path/to/ca/key',
             'cert': '/path/to/ca/cert'
            }
         }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

tl:dr
https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv

---

If I understand correctly you want to access the password for authentication without writing it into the code.

You should take a look at this:
https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv

It lets you read .env files in which you can store your credentials.

Just make sure to NEVER commit the .env file to the version-control system of your choice.
(Use Github's Python .gitignore for example.)